# Violación de segmento al intentar cambiar una variable de otra función con punteros

Tags: c, punteros

Quiero implementar una especie de consola (función `menu_principal`), donde el usuario pueda ir a diferentes menús según su elección. Una de estas opciones es la de entrar en un directorio (función `dir_manager`, se accede con el número 1). Una vez que el usuario quiera finalizar la ejecución debe escribir el número 9 para volver al menú principal y luego el número 0 para salir.

El problema es el siguiente: Primero lo implementé de tal manera que cuando el usuario ingrese a un directorio, mi programa volviese a llamar a `dir_manager`, esta vez con el directorio nuevo al cual el usuario había entrado. Sin embargo, me topé con el conflicto que una vez el usuario quisiera salir, tenía que escribir 9 tantas veces como carpetas entró (ya que al realizarse de manera recursiva entró n veces a la misma función, luego debe salir n veces)

Por lo que se me ocurrió cambiarlo y usar punteros, de forma que cuando el usuario entre a una carpeta, la función `dir_manager` haga un `retorn` normal (yendo a la función que lo llamó, es decir, `menu_principal`) pero que volviese a entrar a `dir_manager` directamente al dejar la variable opción = 2.

Sin embargo a la hora de realizar la asignación, me retorna Violación de segmento (`core' generado):

```
//MAIN
int main(){
    int opcion1 = -1;
    int opcion2 = -1;
    int lvl = 0;
    char from[150] = "./libros/";
    char current[150], to[150];

    strcpy(current, from);
    strcpy(to, from);

    menu_principal(&opcion1, &opcion2, &from, &current, &to, &lvl);
}

void menu_principal(int *opcion1, int *opcion2, char *from, char *current, char *to, int *lvl){
     printf("[MENU PRINCIPAL] Escriba opcion:\n");
     scanf("%i", opcion1);
     while (*opcion1!=0){    
        if (*opcion1==1){
            dir_manager(&opcion1, &opcion2, from, current, to, &lvl);
        }
        else if(*opcion1==0){
            printf("Adios\n");
            return;
        }
    }
}

void dir_manager(int *opcion1, int *opcion2, char *from, char *current, char *to, int *lvl){
    while (*opcion2!=9){
        printf("[DIR MANAGER] Escriba opcion:\n");
        scanf("%i", opcion2);

        if (*opcion2==1){
            char directorio[150];
            printf("Escriba directorio al que quiera entrar:\n");
            scanf("%s", directorio);
            strcat(to, directorio);
            strcat(to, "/");
            printf("Entrando a directorio: %s\n", to);
            *opcion1 = 1;         // <---- ACÁ SE PRODUCE EL ERROR
            return;
        }
        else if(*opcion1==9){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Si tienes comentarios sobre la forma en la que usaste la respuesta, edita la pregunta o comenta la respuesta. No modifiques la respuesta original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente tienes estos dos problemas:

En la llamada a la función menu_principal dentro de la función main, le pones & a las variables from, current y to, las cuales son arreglos de caracteres, por lo que ya son por definición apuntadores al inicio de esos arreglos.

En la llamada a dir_manager dentro de la función menu_principal, le pones & a las variables opcion1, opcion2 y lvl, cuando menu_principal las recibió como apuntadores a enteros.

Adicionalmente, para evitar los warnings, pon antes del main los prototipos de las funciones menu_principal y dir_manager, y agrega los headers necesarios.

Tu código puede quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void menu_principal(int *opcion1, int *opcion2, char *from, char *current, char *to, int *lvl);
void dir_manager(int *opcion1, int *opcion2, char *from, char *current, char *to, int *lvl);


int main(){
    int opcion1 = -1;
    int opcion2 = -1;
    int lvl = 0;
    char from[150] = "./libros/";
    char current[150], to[150];

    strcpy(current, from);
    strcpy(to, from);

    menu_principal(&opcion1, &opcion2, &from, &current, &to, &lvl);
}

void menu_principal(int *opcion1, int *opcion2, char *from, char *current, char *to, int *lvl){
      while (*opcion1!=0){
         printf("[MENU PRINCIPAL] Escriba opcion:\n");
        scanf("%i", opcion1);

        if (*opcion1==1){
            dir_manager(&opcion1, &opcion2, from, current, to, &lvl);
        }
        else if(*opcion1==0){
            printf("Adios\n");
            return;
        }
    }
}

void dir_manager(int *opcion1, int *opcion2, char *from, char *current, char *to, int *lvl){
    while (*opcion2!=9){
        printf("[DIR MANAGER] Escriba opcion:\n");
        scanf("%i", opcion2);

        if (*opcion2==1){
            char directorio[150];
            printf("Escriba directorio al que quiera entrar:\n");
            scanf("%s", directorio);
            strcat(to, directorio);
            strcat(to, "/");
            printf("Entrando a directorio: %s\n", to);
            *opcion1 = 1;         // <---- ACÁ SE PRODUCE EL ERROR
            return;
        }
        else 
            if(*opcion1==9){
                return;
            }
    }
 }
```